# How do I modify, via PowerShell, Windows Group Policy settings that don't have a Registry setting?

Tags: windows, powershell, gpo, policies

I need to apply specific Group Policy related settings (not all of them have Registry setting equivalents) across multiple systems; preferably using a PowerShell script.

I've scoured the Internet and all GPO modification examples using PowerShell refer to setting the Registry equivalent's value.  What about for GPOs that don't have a Registry setting equivalent for them?

First, am I correct that some GPOs aren't represented in the Registry?
Second, if that's correct ... is there a way to change the settings for those non-Registry GPOs via PowerShell?

Exporting GPOs and importing them produced flakey behavior across systems.  I tried using LGPO.exe to create a backup and the import that backup to other similar systems but it's not trustworthy and I guess not recommended from what I read.

I need a way to set GPOs (that do not have a Registry key associated with them) programmatically on multiple systems.  The idea is to update systems rather than restore them (with an MDT image).

Thank you.

Exporting GPOs with LGPO.exe on one system and importing them on another similar system.  "gpupdate /force" failures.  Failed to load Computer Policy.  Need this to work consistently.

Comment: Incidentally, these are standalone systems ... not on a network where setting them on the DC, AD, whatever will work.  There's a very good reason these are not on a network but are standalone systems.

Comment: Many GPOs evoke a change to another registry value, distinct from the values in the `Policies` key where the GPOs exist.  Which are you talking about?

Comment: THANK YOU so much for your response, Ben.  That's good to know.  In this case, I need to set the GPO "User Account Control: Behavior of the elevation prompt for administrators in Admin Approval Mode" set to "Elevate without prompting".  And, "User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode" set to "Enabled".  I know how to programmatically set UAC via the Registry but I don't want UAC disabled across board; just for the Administrator user that replaces the built-in Administrator account.

Comment: I hope you're prompting the local admin before making changes that reduce their security like that.  I suspect your export works fine, and the import and gpupdate are failing because you aren't running them in an elevated admin context.  (You're used to admin automatically being elevated, by configuration, but you don't have that configuration active yet.  Chicken and egg.)

Comment: This question on ServerFault may help you: https://serverfault.com/a/911230/28549

Comment: Thank you again, Ben.  Yeah ... I ran all my "gpupdate /force" attempts from Command Prompt as Administrator.  But good question.  And thank you for the reference to serverfault.com.  It looks like that might be the way I should and need to go.  I so appreciate it.